# Button Highlight - how to apply onTouch to 2 buttons

Tags: android, button, highlight, touch-event

i have 2 buttons like this:

```
Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("Button onw");
        b.setId(1111);
        b.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.button);
        b.setOnTouchListener(listenerOne);
        rootLayout.addView(b);

        Button b1 = new Button(this);
        b1.setText("Button two");
        b1.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.button);
        b1.setOnTouchListener(listenerOne);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams i = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, UIUtils.convertDPToPixels(activity
            .getResources().getDisplayMetrics(), 45));
        i.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, b.getId());
        rootLayout.addView(b1, i);
```

Now this is my onTouch :

```
OnTouchListener listenerOne = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        view.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#B7B2B0"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        view.invalidate();
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
        view.invalidate();
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
        view.invalidate();
        break;
        }
        return false;
    }
    };
```

Now problem here is when i touch one button the 2nd button also gets highlighted ? why so whats wrong here?

Comment: It doesn't even look like you're using your onTouchListener...

Comment: @Cornholio sorry updated my code

Comment: This is really strange behavior - Any reason you're not using a normal onClickListener?

Comment: @Cornholio why because onClick will not give the onTouch effect, like down,up etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use a Anonymous inner class as below

```
    b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             b.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             b.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
        }

            return true;
    }

    });
```

Similarly for button b1

```
    b1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
        }

            return true;
    }

    });
```

Edit: I used the above code. It works fine. When ever the button in touched ondown color changes to blue and on up changes to green.

```
            b1.setOnTouchListener(listenerOne);
    b.setOnTouchListener(listenerOne);
```

And Listener

```
             OnTouchListener listenerOne = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);


        break;
        }
        return false;
    }
    };
```

Edit 2:

```
          b.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);//default background  color green
      b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); // default background  color green
```

Use the code in edit or anonymous inner class

[image]

On Touch Down

[image]

On Release button background will be green again

Comment: why this will work and why my code will not work ? we are doing same in both onTouch so why cant we assign the to both the buttons?

Comment: i have used your code and i don't seem to regenerate you problem.

Comment: well you don't need to call invalidate.Not sure what's the problem. I can't reproduce your problem as an alternative you can use anonymous inner class. do you have on click on your button along with on touch??

Comment: thanks for your answer , but this will work for setting the background of button, but i am trying to highlight a button

Comment: you can also use a selector in xml to highlight a button on click and on release return to normal state is that what your looking for?

Comment: yes i had used it but i want to do it programatically without using any images

Comment: @Goofy you can set a a color for button default state. ontouch down set a new color and on release set the default color as background. This should work

Comment: No buddy i cant use the xmls thats the disadvantage :(

Comment: @Goofy use the above touch listener no need for xmls

Comment: yes i am using the same as i said it will work for setting the background but not for highlighting a buttonm

Comment: you set a different background color for the button that should give you an effect of highlighting a button

Comment: @Goofy to make it clear i have added snap shots. this will give you an effect of button highlight

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
setBackgroundResource(R.color.rojo);
```

you can use string also to define the color but it should define in resource.